# Python argparse with optional nargs ath the end of multiple subparsers

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to achieve the following command definition with argparse, but I can't seem to figure it out:
`script.py {scan,list} ... [targets [targets...]]`

I've gone through the complete documentation and checked multiple different questions which were somewhat related, however, I can't find a resource which seems to address the specific way I want to implement it.

What I want is two different subparsers (scan and list), which both have a shared OPTIONAL and POSITIONAL argument as the LAST ARGUMENT (with `nargs=*`).

These are the approaches I attempted so far, but as you'll see, each of them has a different issue with them.

1. Using a parent parser on the subparsers. This works, however, it has the following issues:

- The "targets" argument is not shown in the main help section of the script. (so when running `script.py -h`, I get `[-h] {scan,list} ...` instead of `[-h] {scan,list} ... [targets [targets...]]`
- The proxy argument will be placed AFTER the targets argument. I want "targets" to be at the end at all times.

```py
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parent_parser.add_argument('targets', type=str, nargs='*', default="ALL")

    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    parser_scan = subparsers.add_parser('scan', parents = [parent_parser])
    parser_scan.add_argument('proxy', type=str)

    parser_list = subparsers.add_parser('list', parents = [parent_parser])
```

2. Adding it manually to all parsers separately:

- This works as well, but the "targets" argument is again not shown in the main help section of the script. (so when running `script.py -h`, I get `[-h] {scan,list} ...` instead of `[-h] {scan,list} ... [targets [targets...]]`
- The help section can be fixed by uncommenting the 3rd line, however, then the targets argument of the subparser is overwritten by the main parser. As a result `args.targets` will always return the default value "ALL", regardless of whether you pass targets to the script or not...

```py
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    # parser.add_argument('targets', type=str, nargs='*', default="ALL")

    parser_scan = subparsers.add_parser('scan')
    parser_scan.add_argument('proxy', type=str)
    parser_scan.add_argument('targets', type=str, nargs='*', default="ALL")

    parser_list = subparsers.add_parser('list')
    parser_list.add_argument('targets', type=str, nargs='*', default="ALL")
```

3. Only adding the argument to the main parser:

- In this case, the help section of the main script correctly shows  `[-h] {scan,list} ... [targets [targets...]]`
- However, when running the script like this: `script.py list Target1`, I get the error message:

```
usage: target-utils.py [-h] {scan,list} ... [targets [targets ...]]
target-utils.py: error: unrecognized arguments: Target1
```

```py
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    parser.add_argument('targets', type=str, nargs='*', default="ALL")

    parser_scan = subparsers.add_parser('scan')
    parser_scan.add_argument('proxy', type=str)

    parser_list = subparsers.add_parser('list')
```

Comment: Once the main parser passes the action to the subparser, it is done parsing (except for error cleanup).  Don't think of those final arguments as 'shared'.  `subparsers` doesn't implement that, either in parsing or help.

Comment: So then how do achieve what I'm trying to do? I assume I'm not the only one trying to do something like this :)
In fact, I have seen other python programs which are able to do this, but don't think they use argparse. Is this a limitation of argparse?

Comment: `add_subparsers` creates a `positional` argument with a special Action class, and a `nargs='+...'`.  So `subparsers` is an argument Action object that gets all of the remaining `argv` values, and the first must be one of the `parser` choices.  That's what use usage attempts to convey, ` {scan,list} ...`.  The main parser can have other other arguments, including positionals, but they shouldn't have a flexible `nargs`.  Generally it's best to only give the main parser flagged arguments, which will be handled before the subparsers.

Comment: If other programs allow for some sort of shared `targets` list at the end, they aren't using `argparse`, or at least not its `subparsers` mechanism.

Comment: I would go with option number 2 and then create a custom usage statement for the main parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subparsers is a relatively simple, and modular, addition to the basic parsing.  Most of the work is done by a custom `Action` subclass.  So there isn't a lot of flexibility, in setup, parsing, or help, beyond what's documented.

To clarify how subparsers works, and expand on my comments, let's define a parser:

```
In [46]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ...: parser.add_argument('--foo')
    ...: parser.add_argument('bar')
    ...: sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')
    ...: sp1 = sp.add_parser('test')
    ...: sp1.add_argument('xxx');

In [47]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--foo FOO] bar {test} ...

positional arguments:
  bar
  {test}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO

In [48]: sp1.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py bar test [-h] xxx

positional arguments:
  xxx

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Here I define all arguments for the main, followed by the subparsers.  The main usage attempts to show that `test` gets all trailing strings.  The main parser does not return to parsing after passing the task to the subparser.

I could add a positional to the main after setting up the subparsers, and that will be reflected in the usage:

```
In [49]: parser.add_argument('targets',nargs='*');

In [50]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--foo FOO] bar {test} ... [targets ...]

positional arguments:
  bar
  {test}
  targets

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO
```

But the actual parsing does not see that added positional.

Parsing with the original main arguments goes fine:

```
In [51]: parser.parse_args('--foo 1 barval test testval'.split())
Out[51]: Namespace(foo='1', bar='barval', cmd='test', targets=[], xxx='testval')
```

But attempting to add 'targets' at the end fails - because the `test` parser does not recognize them.  It just puts them in the "unrecognized" category, and the main just passes that on to the exit.

```
In [52]: parser.parse_args('--foo 1 barval test testval 1 2 3'.split())
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--foo FOO] bar {test} ... [targets ...]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 1 2 3
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

C:\Users\paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3377: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

If I change `test xxx` to `nargs='*'`, these would have been parsed. (adding a new `targets` to `sp1` would be clearer).

```
In [57]: sp1._actions[1].nargs='*'
In [58]: parser.parse_args('--foo 1 barval test testval 1 2 3'.split())
Out[58]: Namespace(foo='1', bar='barval', cmd='test', targets=[], xxx=['testval', '1', '2', '3'])

In [59]: sp1.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py bar test [-h] [xxx ...]

positional arguments:
  xxx

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

The key points are that:

- once the parsing is passed to the subparser, the main does not do any more parsing.
- trying to add positionals after the subparsers does not work - for the above reason.  The help may show them there, but that's not reflecting the parsing
- using '*' (or '+?') `positionals` in the main is not a good idea.  To the main, `subparsers` is just a specialized `positional`.  It is recognized by position, not value.
- It is best not use the same `dest` for the main and the subparsers.  The subparsers default will always override the main.
- parents is just a convenience tool, saving some typing when adding similar arguments to multiple subparsers.  It doesn't do anything special.